# google map link with marker (on iphone & android)

Tags: iphone, android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I've tried to open Google Map application on iphone & android. From iPhone developer reference website I am able to open the native google map from link.

http://maps.google.com/maps?ll=11.5558762589,104.921697935&z=15

However, I have trouble with adding a marker into the map. As in google static map, we can add markers into map. I wonder if we can do the same to google map link.

Comment: Are you trying to do this from a web site or a native application?

Comment: Note that since iOS 6, you have to convert all map requests from "maps.google.com" to "maps.apple.com" for the iOS map to activate. Rather annoying really.

Answer (score 6):

Hey Borey
You can add markers. But it has to be google's own preset marker.
Try this link :
http://maps.google.com/?q=5.352135,100.299683&z=17

Use q instead of ll and I think it will work.

Problems I saw:
1) Cannot choose your own marker
2) Cannot remove that 'additional marker' that tells you what's around that area.

I guess, that's the next best thing for you? For your info, I am using it too as I lack other choices.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I am aware of for doing this is to use the *My Maps* feature of google maps. You can create a public map in *My Maps*. Add a marker using the toolbar in the map, then use the link button on the top right to get the [URL of your public map](http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&hl=en&msa=0&ll=-33.854094,151.207151&spn=0.042411,0.071325&t=h&z=14&msid=109115301202341389527.00049253cee2a50e8762a).

Not sure how this looks on a mobile device, but I assume that it works.

**Edit**

Ok. So my assumption was incorrect. I tried this out on Android and iPhone and got the following results:

- iPhone - Switches out to the maps application (no option to view in the browser), displays the correct region, but no markers.
- Android - Gives you the option of viewing the URL in the browser or in maps.  If you view in the browser, you get the correct region, but no markers.
- Android - If you view on the maps application, you get the correct region and the markers.

So basically not very useful to you.  When I have done this in my mobile web apps (not native), I have used static maps.  You give up the dynamic functionality, but you get [lots of flexibility](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-maps/info) with what gets rendered on the map.

Comment: This url only work in browser. I think Google Map application on phone doesn't understand the url generated by My Maps feature.

Comment: @Borey Tried out the my maps URL and it seems this is not the right approach for you.